# How to use new HTML5 tags with ViewModel in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I would like to use the new HTML5 tags with my `ViwModel` (specifically, I want to use the `date picker` control and bind it to a `DateTime` property in my `ViewModel`), is there any extension method for them?

For example, if I want to bind a text editor to a property in my `ViewModel`, I can write something like this inside a `form`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyTestProperty)
```

While with HTML5 tags, I only know something like this (as an individual `input` element):

```
<input id="myDate" name="myDate" type="date" value="">
```

The problem with it is I can only get the value from Request.Form["myDate"] and it is only a string value. Can I bind the value of HTML5 element to my `ViewModel`?

UPDATE:

Thank you for all who pointed out that this is a duplicate question. But I can't seem to get it work with referenced question. Is marking `DateTypeAttribute` the only thing I need to do and after that the `EditorFor` extension method would render an `input` with type `date`? Because I tried that but nothing happened.

Comment: Is `MyTestProperty` typeof `DateTime`? If so add the `[DataType]` and `[DisplayFormat]` attributes, but keep in mind that `type="date"` is only supported in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for this.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyTestProperty, new {@id="datetimepicker1"})
```

Then you need below js to activate it. You can just add this inside document.ready().

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: OP is asking how to generate the HTML5 inputs, not use a jQuery plugin